# trio.Event(): Which is “better”: setting and initializing a new Event or checking if someone is waiting for it beforehand?

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-trio

```
import trio

work_available = trio.Event()

async def get_work():
  while True:
    work = check_for_work()
    if not work:
      await work_available.wait()
    else:
      return work

def add_work_to_pile(...):
  ...
  if work_available.statistics().tasks_waiting:
    global work_available
    work_available.set()
    work_available = trio.Event()
```

In this Python-like code example I get work in bursts via `add_work_to_pile()`. The workers which get work via `get_work()` are slow. So most of the time `add_work_to_pile()` is called there will be no one waiting on `work_available`.

**Which is better/cleaner/simpler/more pythonic/more trionic/more intended by the trio developers?**

- checking if someone is looking for the `Event()` via `statistics().tasks_waiting`, like in the example code, ...or...
- unconditionally `set()` setting the `Event()` and creating a new one each time? (Most of them in vain.)

Furthermore... the API does not really seem to expect regular code to check if someone is waiting via this `statistics()` call...

I don’t mind spending a couple more lines to make things clearer. But that goes both ways: a couple CPU cycles more are fine for simpler code...

Comment: According to the [docs](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#trio.Event), "If you need to represent a series of events, consider creating a new Event object for each one (they’re cheap!)"

Comment: @user2357112 I remember reading that in the docs as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new `Event` is roughly the same cost as creating the `_EventStatistics` object within the `statistics` method. You'll need to profile your own code to pick out any small difference in performance. However, although it is safe and performant, the intent of `statistics` across trio's classes is for debug rather than core logic. Using/discarding many `Event` instances would be relatively more along the intent of the devs.

A more trionic pattern would be to load each work item into a buffered [memory channel](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#using-channels-to-pass-values-between-tasks) in place of your `add_work_to_pile()` method and then iterate on that in the task that awaits `get_work`. I feel the amount of code is comparable to your example:

```py
import trio

send_chan, recv_chan = trio.open_memory_channel(float('inf'))

async def task_that_uses_work_items():
    # # compare
    # while True:
    #     work = await get_work()
    #     handle_work(work)
    async for work in recv_chan:
        handle_work(work)

def add_work_to_pile():
    ...
    for work in new_work_set:
        send_chan.send_nowait(work)

# maybe your work is coming in from a thread?
def add_work_from_thread():
    ...
    for work in new_work_set:
        trio_token.run_sync_soon(send_chan.send_nowait, work)
```

Furthermore, it's performant because the work items are efficiently rotated through a `deque` internally. This code would checkpoint for every work item so you may have to jump through some hoops if you want to avoid that.

Comment: A channel makes sense but getting the work items is a bit awkward. First you need to wait for at least one item and put into a list: `items = [await receive_channel.receive()]`; then you need to get any remaining items using `receive_channel.receive_nowait()`, append each one to that list, wrapped in a `while True` which is further wrapped in `try:` / `except trio.WouldBlock: pass`.

Comment: I have done something like that pattern before :) : https://github.com/richardsheridan/magic-afm/blob/642caf2cec3e24665375b205027d363faf072d60/magic_afm/gui.py#L252-L259 Maybe just make a helper function `get_all_queued(recv_chan)` to move the details of vacuuming up the buffer out of your main logic flow.

Comment: I updated the question to clear up my intentions (I prefer clear/clean code over CPU cycles within reason.) The channel solution seems to be a lot more code to write for little benefit if at all. – But you seem to indicate that setting creating a new Event unconditionally is totally reasonable to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want a [`trio.ParkingLot`](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-lowlevel.html#trio.lowlevel.ParkingLot). It gives more control over parking (i.e. which is like `Event.wait()`) and unparking (which is like `Event.set()` except that it doesn't stop future parkers from waiting). But it doesn't have any notion of being set *at all* so you would need to store that information separately. If you work is naturally Truety when set (e.g. a non-empty list) then that might be easy anyway. Example:

```
available_work = []
available_work_pl = trio.ParkingLot()

async def get_work():
    while not available_work:
        await available_work_pl.park()
    result = list(available_work)
    available_work.clear()
    return result

def add_work_to_pile():
    available_work.append(foo)
    available_work_pl.unpark()
```

Edit: Replaced "if" with "while" in `get_work()`. I think `if` has a race condition: if there are two parked tasks and then `add_work_to_pile()` gets called twice, then one `get_work()` would get both work items but the other would still be unparked and return an empty list. Using `while` instead will make it loop back around until more data is added.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you don't want an event in the first place. The combination of an array and something that tells the reader there's work in the array is already available as [memory channels](https://trio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference-core.html#using-channels-to-pass-values-between-tasks). They have the additional advantage that you       can tell them how much work to accept before the sender stalls.

```
send_channel, recv_channel = trio.open_memory_channel(10)

get_work = recv_channel.receive
add_work_to_pile = send_channel.send
# both are async functions or use the _nowait() versions
```

Comment: Furthermore, I need control over which work I pick next from the pile. They have different and changing priorities.